# ZXing CaptureActivity back button issue

Tags: android

I'm having issues with integrating my project with ZXing CaptureActivity. Everything seems to work great. But when I'm  canceling CaptureActivity it's finishing but the onKeyUp implementation of previous activity is also called. I'm having this issue only in portrait mode. Maybe someone had similar problem.

Please tell me if I have to clarify my question with some code, I'm just hoping that it's a simple question and I've just forgotten about some stupid minor details in my program.